# HttpServer within junit fails with address in use error after first test

Tags: java, junit, com.sun.net.httpserver

I have a Java class for use with JUnit 4.x. Within each @Test method I create a new HttpServer, with port 9090 used. The first invocation works find, but subsequent ones error with "Address is already in use: bind".

Here's an example:

```
@Test
public void testSendNoDataHasValidResponse() throws Exception {
    InetSocketAddress address = new InetSocketAddress(9090);
    HttpHandler handler = new HttpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
            byte[] response = "Hello, world".getBytes();
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, response.length);
            exchange.getResponseBody().write(response);
            exchange.close();
        }
    };
    HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(address, 1);
    server.createContext("/me.html", handler);
    server.start();

    Client client = new Client.Builder(new URL("http://localhost:9090/me.html"), 20, "mykey").build();

    client.sync();
    server.stop(1);
    assertEquals(true, client.isSuccessfullySynchronized());
}
```

Clearly the HttpServer is held solely within each method and is stopped before the end. I fail to see what's continuing to hold any sockets open. The first test passes, subsequent ones fail every time.

Any ideas?

EDIT with corrected method:

```
@Test
public void testSendNoDataHasValidResponse() throws Exception {
    server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 0), 1);
    HttpHandler handler = new HttpHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
            byte[] response = "Hello, world".getBytes();
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, response.length);
            exchange.getResponseBody().write(response);
            exchange.close();
        }
    };
    server.createContext("/me.html", handler);
    server.start();
    InetSocketAddress address = server.getAddress();
    String target = String.format("http://%s:%s/me.html", address.getHostName(), address.getPort());

    Client client = new Client.Builder(new URL(target), 20, "mykey").build();

    client.sync();
    server.stop(0);
    assertEquals(true, client.isSuccessfullySynchronized());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usually a 2 minute wait time before you can rebind to a specific port number.  Run netstat to confirm if your server's connection is in TIME_WAIT.  If so, you can get around it by using the SO_REUSEADDR option before binding.  Docs are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29) for java.

Comment: I can see that - thanks for the hint. Now if I use this while firing up an HttpServer the problem would be solved...

Answer (score 6):

jello's answer is on the money.

Other workarounds:

- Reuse the same HttpServer for all your tests. To clean it up between tests, you can remove all its contexts. If you give it a custom executor, you can also wait for or kill off all the worker threads too.
- Create each HttpServer on a new port. You can do this by [specifying a port number of zero when creating the InetSocketAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html#InetSocketAddress%28int%29). You can then find the actual port in useby [querying the server for its port](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html#getAddress%28%29) after creating it, and use that in tests.
- [Change the global server socket factory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSocketFactory%28java.net.SocketImplFactory%29) to a custom factory which returns the same server socket every time. That lets you reuse the same actual socket for many tests, without having to reuse the HttpServer.

Answer (score 0):

When you create HttpServer, you specified

> the maximum number of queued incoming connections to allow on the
>   listening socket

which is **1**

```
server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 0), 1);
```

[link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html#create(java.net.InetSocketAddress,%20int))